# Staying logged in during Selenium test

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run a selenium test while staying logged in and access a page that can only be accessed under certain user permissions.

I first login using selenium commands, and it appears successful. But after I login and the use command (website links removed)

```
chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.website.com/otherpage");
```

It redirects to the wrong page because I'm no longer logged in.

Any reason why?

Comment: Need more information.  The Login should be maintained in a cookie or session that is stored locally and synched up with the server that performs authentication.  As long as the cache for the browser is the same and no logout code was executed to cause the cookie/session to not validate with the server correctly this should work.  Does this work manually?  If so please provide more details on the steps you are doing via Selenium and the html related to those steps.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question description is quite poor, but you can consider the following - By default when *driver* is created, you get **clean** instance of the browser (no add-ins, extensions etc.). You can change that if you set user-profiles that will be used over default one. This could be one of the reasons why manually your tests pass and when you execute them they can't pass.

Also try to find what is the *keep-alive* session and is there any specific requirement, that can prevents your login (test)logic. Could it be test-user privileges to access these resources?

Answer (score 0):

@Hoang - this so called by You "backdoor" is simply bad practice (if not dangerous)! Why!? Please read [URL_Manipulation](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/URL-manipulation-URL-rewriting) and [Web_Parameter_Tampering](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Web_Parameter_Tampering).

Also please keep in mind that a lot of people read this Q&A site. Such "advices" must be double-checked before given.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If you test for your *internal dev* team. Ask them to provide you a backdoor

you could login to page chrome.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.website.com/otherpage?username=foo&password=fooo");